# Pycharm's Django `Run manage.py Task` console not working for interactive commands?

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose, pycharm, manage.py

When I use Pycharm's built-in Django `Run manage.py Task...` console, everything works well, until the command expects some user input.

For example `makemigrations` and `migrate` commands work just fine, because they don't require any additional user input:

[image: working command]

But commands which require some intermediate input (like `createsuperuser` needs the credentials for the superuser and `collectstatic` needs the "Y" confirmation) don't work at all. The input prompts don't show up, and typing in the console does nothing:

[image: non working command]

**This only happens when I'm using a docker-compose interpreter for a Django project.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's now clear that this is simply a bug in Pycharm, here's the associated bug report: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-41974.